# How to nest params using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I want to create XML like this:

```
<categories>
 <category id=1>Sound</category>
 <category id=2 parentId=1>Speakers</category>
</categories>
```

I used:

```
   require 'nokogiri'
    @builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      xml.root {
        xml.categories{
           Category.all.each do |c|
             xml.category# here i should insert my needs

      end
    }
  }
end
```

I used an example from "[docs about Tag Attribute Short Cuts](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder)" but it gave me `class` and `id` instead what I want.

How do I do it properly?

Comment: I am not sure, can you try xml.category.set_attribute('id', c.id) inside the loop

Comment: no doesn't work =>`<category class="set_attribute">id</category>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will add the `id` attribute to the category tag:

```
require 'nokogiri'
  @builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root {
    xml.categories{
       Category.all.each do |c|
         xml.category(c.name, "id" => c.id)
  end
  }
}
end
```

Output should be like:

```
<categories>
 <category id=1>Sound</category>
 <category id=2>Speakers</category>
</categories
```

Comment: nice,exactly what i need